# Gridview Update Button Collapse jQuery Trigger

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with my current project. I am making an Admin page from where the user can edit text on the website. It is all collected on 1 page and inserted into jQuerys like this page demonstrates:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/easy-toggle-jquery-tutorial/

Inside my Gridview I have update and delete buttons (those generated from the Dataset I'm using), but when I click "Update" the jQuery trigger collapses and therefore, I will have to open the trigger again before I can edit the area.

Is it possible somehow to let the jQuery Trigger STAY open when I click on the update button?

I believe it's because of a postback so I've been researching for "How to prevent postback", but the most answers I could find was how to prevent postback on a ASP:BUTTON - which is not my case :)

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to enter my entire codes because those Gridview and datasources are pretty long I think.

Answer (score 0):

This code (from the tutorial you linked) collapses the container when the page loads:

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
```

You need to have some way to know that the reason the page is loading is because the page is doing a Postback.  One way to do this is to have a `asp:HiddenField` field on your page, then set it's value to "True" if you're doing a postback, and false otherwise.  You could do that in your `Page_Load` method (in code behind) like this:

```
Page_Load (Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        myHdnField.Value = "True";
    }
    else
    {
        myHdnField.Value = "False";
    }
}
```

Then, you would just need to check that in your javascript to decide whether or not to collapse the container.  **Edit: Per our comments, you may need to wait on the DOM to be ready.  Here I've used jQuery to check that (I added the reference to jQuery as well)**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        if(document.getElementByID('<%= myHdnField.ClientID %>').value == "False")
        {
            $(".toggle_container").hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey Jadarnel27, I did as you suggested and noticed that the containers keeps being open as if the jquery isn't there at all.

Comment: @MikeB My mistake, I used `=` instead of `==` to do the comparison in that javascript snippet.  Try the updated code and see if that works for you.

Comment: Cheers Jadarnel, I think I might be doing things wrong here due to my lack of knowledge ;) But I've entered the code-behind in the page_load. But the javascript is a bit confusing, am I supposed to simple overwrite my javascript with yours? :)

Comment: @MikeB Correct! Just overwrite your javascript with the sample at the bottom and that _should_ do it. Also, make sure you have added the asp:HiddenField to the page =)

Comment: Cheers buddy, I tried to overwrite my existen Javascript with yours but the jQuery stays open now. I don't know if it helps but you can see my Default.aspx and my Default.aspx.cs files here: www.Sp34k.com/stackoverflow/Default.aspx and stackoverflow/Default.aspx.cs - Not sure what causes the issue, I have done everything correct (or so I think hehe).

Comment: @MikeB Well that ***is*** odd!  Are you getting any javascript errors?  It could be that you need to wait on the DOM to be ready.  I'll update the javascript code real quick to show how to do that.

Comment: @MikeBertelsen Just curious, did this end up helping you out with this problem?